# What's the best way to draw a stroke/outline around Sprite Kit's SKLabelNode?

Tags: sprite-kit

What's the best way to draw a stroke/outline around Sprite Kit's SKLabelNode?

Answer (score 0):

The **best** way in my opinion is to not use the SKLabelNode and instead use a bitmap font.

1) BMGlyph - http://www.bmglyph.com/tutorials-spritekit-bitmap-font/

2) Glyph Designer - https://71squared.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200037472-Using-Glyph-Designer-1-8-with-Sprite-Kit

Both are great and will get the job done. I personally prefer BMGlyph because you get access to the code and the code is the same for OS X and iOS.

---

You could also design the font in a graphics editor but font typically needs to be more dynamic so this may not work for you.

A more "hacky" solution is to place 2 SKLabelNodes on top of each other and create a similar effect that way.